# Android: Generic container / Views / View.OnClickListeners

Tags: android

I have a container, usually a common `LinearLayout`, where I want to add views. After the user clicks on a view, the view should be removed from the container. Obviously, I can implement the functionality in an `OnClickListener`, and attach it to the view.

But, if another programmer forgets, to remove the view, after doing his stuff in his `OnClickListener`, the view will remain in the container.

Is there a way, that the container can enforce the removal? I haven't seen a `View#getOnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create your own container and when `addView` is called you can modify the view's `onClickListener`.

EDIT:

This is not possible since there is no `getOnClickListener` and also the variable that holds the listener has the `{@hide}`.

I guess the only way out if extending each `View` and overriding the `setOnClickListener` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I modify the View's onClickListener, since there is no getOnClickListener method? Basically, I must extend the behaviour of the attached OnClickListener, doing the stuff, the view wants to do with it and then the "remove from container" stuff...